# scraping - limited search results availability

Tags: r, search, web-scraping, rvest

So I wanted to have some used-cars price database to do some data analysis across various brands, countries, fuel types etc.

I found couple of websites that have this information and extracted some data. But I also wanted to extract data from autoscout24.com.

I am using R's rvest package and usually all I need to do is to write a loop that goes through all the search results and collects information from each individual listing.

What I found interesting with Autoscout, is that it is impossible to view all the search results. Say, you go to their webpage https://www.autoscout24.com/, choose country and press Results. Then on the Results page there are only first 20 pages each containing 20 listings. And nothing changes when you go to the last search result page. So, basically, you only can view up to 400 search results.

I was thinking if that is made so with purpose so that somebody (like myself) wouldn't be able to scrape their data easily? That is totaly fine from my perspective, but I was just curious about this, because I have never seen such a practice in other websites (though I haven't tried to scrape them).

Comment: Can you provide a sample search results ?

Comment: For example, here are the search results for all car listings in Austria https://www.autoscout24.com/results?pricefrom=0&cy=A&powertype=kw&atype=C&ustate=N%2CU&sort=price&desc=0 . We can see that there are more than 100k results, but only 400 can actually be accessed.

Comment: Yeah, it's some kind of protection so they don't get their database scrapped too easily. You cannot even modify then in the URL, i tried changing page to page=21 but I got an error

Comment: Isn't it quite an unusual solution? I mean, they do not allow their users to access the information. Of course, most of the times clients should be interested in more specific results, but still. Aren't API's usually used to limit what data can be accessed?

Comment: They are indeed limiting access to their API. Maybe you could investigate a little bit further and try to see how their API is implemented and exploit it (finding endpoints and stuff using the "network" tab of your browser). Yet I would recommend moving on to another website